# How can I check if vector elements are in order consecutively?

Tags: c++, vector

I need to check if in my vector the elements are in order consecutively?

```
for(i=1; i<=K; i++)
    if(v[i]=v[i+1]-1)
```

If the statement would be true I want to return the biggest integer.

> ex. 4 5 6 7

```
7
```

Comment: So you want to check if the vector is sorted?

Comment: You want to check its sorted or you want the biggest element (even if its not sorted)?

Comment: it is sorted ascending

Comment: now i got to find if they are consecutive

Comment: `v[i]=v[i+1]-1` this is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: Make up your mind. Sorted, or consecutive?

Comment: Please correct your question. Do you want to find out if your vector is sorted or do you want the largest number ? It is ambiguous at the moment.

Comment: Here is a link for your future questions: http://www.google.com

Comment: @schizoid Please don't post pseudo code here but a [MCVE], and exactly state what your problems or errors are.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's an algorithm for that: [`std::is_sorted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted):

```
if (std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()) {
    return v.back(); // the largest element would be the last one
}
else {
    // ?? 
}
```

Comment: @schizoid That has nothing to do with using `std::is_sorted`

Comment: @schizoid: So instead of fixing that major problem, you gave up and want to live on with a workaround? That's bad. It **must** work with a standard-library solution.

Comment: @ChristianHackl i have no idea how to fix it

Comment: @schizoid Did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: @schizoid: Search Stackoverflow for people who've had the same problem in the past, and reuse the solution.

Comment: i put include algorithm and all that

Comment: but it's a problem if I work with the classic vector?

Comment: @schizoid: There is no such thing as a "classic vector". There is `std::vector` or `std::array`. If you are talking about raw arrays, then yes, it is a problem.

Comment: @ChristianHackl i didn't declare it as a container,I tried to,but it won't let me read it from file,I got an error "operator>>" something like that

Comment: @schizoid: You cannot successfully use C++ without a decent textbook (which should include a section on simple text I/O and `operator>>`). Seriously, it's **hopeless** without a book. Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @ChristianHackl algorithms work fine with raw arrays

Comment: @Galik: Judging from the OP's question and comments, the fact that arrays work with algorithms won't be much of a help.

Comment: @Barry I'm also having an issue where, even though I've included "#include <algorithm>" and "using namespace std;" I receive the error: "is_sorted() was not declared in this scope". Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

> I need to check if in my vector the elements are in order

Use C++11's [`std::is_sorted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 { 4, 5, 7, 6 };
    std::vector<int> v2 { 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    std::cout << std::is_sorted(begin(v1), end(v1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_sorted(begin(v2), end(v2)) << "\n";
}
```

> If the statement would be true I want to return the biggest integer.

That's a job for [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 { 4, 5, 7, 6 };
    std::vector<int> v2 { 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    std::cout << *std::max_element(begin(v1), end(v1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << *std::max_element(begin(v2), end(v2)) << "\n";
}
```

Note that `std::max_element` does **not** require its input to be sorted.

Or if it's sorted anyway, just use `v1.back()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
is_sorted(begin(v), end(v));
```

If the sequence is not sorted then use:

```
max_element(begin(v), end(v));
```

to get the max.

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::is_sorted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) algorithm of STL.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool test(vector<int> v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size()-1; i++)
        if(v[i] > v[i+1])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

If the vector is in order, so the biggest is the last one, that is, `v[v.size()-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

From the question it seems you are interested if the vector elements are consective integers. If that is the case you can use a flag to indicate if the condition holds and do a single iteration:

```
bool consecutive = false;
for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
  if (v[i] != v[i - 1] + 1) {
    consecutive = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (consecutive) {
   cout << v.back() << endl; // the last element is the biggest.
}
```

However your question title suggests you are interested in checking if the vector is sorted. If that is the case you can use the built-in function [std::is_sorted](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_sorted/) that is present since c++11.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse through the vector starting from the second element and keep a flag variable initialized to 0, for each iteration check the following condition :-

```
if(v[i]<v[i-1])
```

if this condition is true, then set the flag to 1 and break out of the loop. After the control moves out of the loop, check the value of flag. If flag is 1, then the vector elements are not in order. Otherwise, if the flag is 0, then the vector elements are in order and you have to print the largest element which is v[v.size()-1].